# objective c get first row in uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row

how do i determine the top row in my uitableview that is currently visible? The table has 200+ rows so when a row is clicked i want to determine the first row number that is currently visible. The idea is that when i go to a detail view page for the table item and come back to the page i can scroll my table exactly to that row ( also my table is all in 1 section if that helps) any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has a `visibleCells` method.  Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells).  If it's more useful to you, there's also [`indexPathsForVisibleRows`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathsForVisibleRows).

Comment: Thanks thats what i was after !